# Google GCM Deprecation - Old Mobile Clients with GCM Token

Tags: google-contacts-api

There are lots of Articles, Blogs, Question/Answers about Migration to FCM from GCM.
Although not very clearly documented is what is going to happen with Older Clients which uses GCM tokens (either old or newly obtained) after April 2019.

My questions are :
1) After April 2019, "most" . GCM services will be stopped.As per google they have mentioned "most". It is not explicitly mentioned what are going to be stopped and what would continue working. Any pointer on this would help.

2) What happens to older clients which still uses GCM Client SDK and obtains new tokens after April 2019 ? Will the clients able to obtain a new token using GCM SDK without any error ? Will those tokens work with FCM with GCM API key or FCM API key from Server side?

Comment: As per writing from the [GCM documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) itself. "As of April 10, 2018, Google has deprecated GCM. The GCM server and client APIs are deprecated and will be removed as soon as April 11, 2019. Migrate GCM apps to [Firebase Cloud Messaging](http://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)(FCM), which inherits the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus many new features. See the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm) to learn more." I think you need to follow the guide provided.