# GCM Deprecation: Old Client SDKs

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

The GCM/FCM documentation is not clear on what would be the expected behavior, after April 11, 2019, for the apps that are already installed but not updated to use FCM SDKs.

Once GCM is defunct, will the old apps (having GCM SDK) continue to get new device tokens?

A similar question was asked here: [Google GCM Deprecation - Old Mobile Clients with GCM Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51638893/google-gcm-deprecation-old-mobile-clients-with-gcm-token)

but did not receive a credible answer.

Comment: *The GCM server and client APIs are deprecated and **will be removed** as soon as April 11, 2019* - what is not clear about that? How would you get a new token if the api is not there anymore